# Added button isn't visible

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I try to add an extra panel to already existing one, switchable with button1, but for some reason any added elements (button1) aren't showing up. Here is the fragment of used code:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("App");
    frame.setSize(1200, 800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    JPanel menu = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    mainPanel.add(menu);
    GridBagConstraints e =  new GridBagConstraints();
    e.gridy = 0;
    e.gridx = 0;
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Catalogue");
    menu.add(button1, e);

    frame.add(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.add(panel);

    (...code....)

    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line, after creating a frame

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: It was already in the code. at the very bottom. Thanks and sorry, I've editted the code. I've also added ti after 'JFrame frame = new JFrame("App")' and button shows for a second, then is replaced by empty panel. I'll look into that.

Comment: Button shows again (permanently) after I resize the window. Any ideas?

Comment: I've removed second 'frame.setVisible(true)' and code is working. Thanks.